# How to grab innerHTML with Selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I'm trying to grab the innerHTML if a popup comes up while doing a task in chrome and then based on the innerHTML either click okay and save or exit. The problem where I am running into is just before the possible pop-up I am in an iframe and need to switch back to the main body. I'm using selenium:

```
main body (possible pop_up *i think*)
   iframe (I am here)
```

Below is some of the code I have, taken out the non-necessary lines:

```
Dim sel As Selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim pop as Object    

Set sel = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

sel.Get URL
' Switch to iframe
Set iframe = sel.FindElementByTag("iframe", 10000)
sel.SwitchToFrame iframe, 5000

code...

' Where the popups sometimes show up
On Error Resume Next
sel.SwitchToDefaultContent
Set pop = sel.FindElementsByClass("popupText", 2000) *Error Could not locate class=popupText
On error goto 0
```

I get this error if I turn off on error resume next even if there are popups. Below is the HTML:

```
<span class="popupText">
  <br />
  *Text* 
  <br />
  <br />
  *Text*
</span>
```

I've tried a couple of other things: not using switchtodefaultcontent, and using switchtoparenframe and nothing seems to work.

There is also a .SwitchToAlert feature in selenium that is not working either...

```
strAlert = sel.SwitchToAlert.Text 'Get nothing
sel.SwitchToAlert.Accept          'Does not do anything
```

Comment: so the popups don't appear with python? What do they say? Anything relevant?

Comment: Yeah, the popups appear with both, however it seems I can't locate the class "popupText" in VBA Selenium. I tried the same code in python and it worked fine yet failed in VBA...

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a workaround to this, it seems like there is an issue with the selenium vba add-in. The workaround:

```
sel.SwitchToDefaultContent
inner_text = Right(sel.PageSource, 1000)
```

Instead I grabbed the page_source after switching to default content (the popup text happened to be at the very end of the html) I then continue to check if a popup (4 different pop_up options) is in the inner_text variable. Then continue from there.

The reason I think this is an issue with the VBA Selenium add-in is I replicated the above code with Python and it worked great... so not sure what was going on there. VBA Selenium is dated about 4 years.